# ng-repeat not updating when coming back from a modal call

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my html:

```
   <li class="col-md-4 my-show-hide-animation" ng-hide="sr.hidden" ng-repeat="sr in gmCtrl.gmSRs" ...
```

The above html page has a button that makes a modal call.
I have another html/js page that can be accessed modally and non-modally.

I have this after coming back from the modal call:

```
  if (!$rootScope.$$listenerCount['sr.CreateDone']) {
          $rootScope.$on('sr.CreateDone', function(event, data) { 
                      ctrl.gmSRs.push(data.sr);
          $uibModalStack.dismissAll();            
      });
  }
```

Now... this actually works over and over again. However, the moment I go into the target html/js in a non-modal way (which also works), the modal way no longer works. In the debugger, I can see the data.sr object being added to the array, and I can see the array being changed, but it's not reflected in the view. Any ideas??? I assume that either I have some sort of scoping issue or its some weird angularjs bug.

Here's the call:

```
      ctrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({templateUrl: "standardresponse/standardresponse.html",
         controller: "StandardresponseController",
         controllerAs: "standardresponseCtrl",
         size: "lg",
         keyboard: true,
         backdrop: 'static',
         windowClass: "app-modal-window",
  });
```

I also added a line of code that shows I only have the 1 listener running.

Comment: You are indeed facing a scoping issue, I can better assist you with fixing the scope if you can post the actual code you use to open your modal.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is changing, but it isn't showing up in the view, this means that the digest cycle isn't properly running on the `$scope`. You could fix this manually by calling `$scope.apply()` but you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually tried that and it throws an error. I assume it's because I'm calling an apply within an implicit apply.

Comment: oh right, that makes sense. how are you accessing the page in a non modal way?

Comment: I have the following on a different page: 

<a href="#/standardresponse/{{sr.id}}">